# How to deal with features with more than 80% missingness

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

I'm working with a really bad clinical dataset, it has 300 samples, 400 features, which will be used for machine learning. My advisor told me about some biologically meaningful features in this dataset and asked me to keep them, but many of them are missing more than 50%, or even more than 80%. What should I do? Does padding with mode affect their performance.

Answer (score 2):

In short: model performance should not degrade given the proper way of imputation and the data missing *at random*, even if the proportion of missing data is large. However, choosing the proper way requires EDA and testing.

Are those features numeric or categorical? What about the target?

Even if they are meaningful, that does not mean they affect the target yet.
If that's a classification problem, it would be a good idea to investigate the distribution of those variables given the target and run t-test/u-test to check whether there is any statistically significant difference. If there's not, you have a valid reason to drop a feature. For the regression case, you may study mutual information, correlations and scatter plots. If both feature and target are categorical, run chi-squared test etc.

Imputing numeric values might be tricky since often we have no idea of the underlying distribution in biology. Still, ~60 samples you've got in your worst case should be enough to estimate. You should study it and see whether imputing mean/median/group median/zero/etc would make sense. Sadly, there's no one perfect way here, you'll have to test what makes your model perform the best way.

Other possible tricks:

- Try predicting missing values first (or use something like KNNImputer).
- Impute a value of your choice **and** add a binary feature signifying whether this value is reliable.
- Impute zeros and try a dimensionality reduction technique which handles sparse vectors (e.g. TruncatedSVD).
- Try models which can handle missing data in a robust way (such as XGBoost).

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is my first question.
The features I'm currently interested in are all simple binary features (yes or no) .I'm currently considering two methods, the first is to fill with the mode, and the second is to fill with a third label different from yes or no.
Could you give me a little more advice based on the binary features?
thank you so much！

Comment: That still depends on understanding your data well. Iif the value is largely dominant, we may assume the mode for the missing data. However, your number of observations is small - chances are, your test set might have very few or no existing values for this column, and imputing mode before splitting would be technically a test data leakage. Also, variables might be dependent: if you group by a certain feature, group modes might differ, but you may not always have enough sample size to be certain.

Comment: Switching from binary to three categories (true-false-unknown) sound like a better idea to start with. Imputing the value on the nearest neighbour basis is also an option (`sklearn.impute.KNNImputer(n_neighbors=1)`).