# VarianceThreshold() not returning expected output

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm on the stage of cleaning categorical variables from my data. More specifically, I'm now removing quasi-constant categorical variables.

I've searched and found that `VarianceThreshold()` from `sklearn.feature_selection` can do the job. However, I've got unexpected results. My piece of code:

```
# Create a temporal dataframe that fill null values with string "null_val", as OrdinalEncoder() doesn't work with null values
temp_df = train_df_cat.fillna("null_val")

# Initiate ordinal encoder and encode the different labels with numbers, then convert result to dataframe
ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder()
temp_df = ord_enc.fit_transform(temp_df)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_df, columns=train_df_cat.columns)

# Get the columns with 90% or more values being constant
var_thr = VarianceThreshold(threshold = 0.1)
var_thr.fit(temp_df)
quasi_constant_cat = [column for column in temp_df.columns
                      if column not in temp_df.columns[var_thr.get_support()]]

# Display results
display(quasi_constant_cat)
```

Returns this:

```
['Street',
 'Utilities',
 'LandSlope',
 'Condition2',
 'Heating',
 'CentralAir',
 'PoolQC']
```

Supposedly, those are the features that have any value present 90% or more of the time. However:

```
display(temp_df["Alley"].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Returns, as I had seen on a plot above:

```
2.00   0.94
0.00   0.03
1.00   0.03
Name: Alley, dtype: float64
```

Therefore, `Alley` feature (and maybe others) has a 94% of the same value `2.00` (which actually is the number imputed for null values in this temp_df), but is not included in the output of the `VarianceThreshold()` function.

What should I change in my code to make this function work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance in this particular case would be `(1.91^2 * 0.94 + 1^2 * 0.03) - (1.91 * 0.94 + 1 * 0.03)^2 = 0.1419 > 0.1`

Looks like you'll need a bit higher threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't know about that formula for the variance (I only know the one that uses the summation of individual sum of squared errors). Could you please tell me where to see the general formula that you've applied to my case?

Comment: Consider the basic formula `Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2]`. Expanding the inner brackets, we get the alternate formula `Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2` (see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) or pretty much any stats textbook). Now, calculating means themselves is trivial enough: just calculate the products of possible values and their respective probabilities and sum them.

Comment: On a related note, you'd probably be better with one hot encoding for this column. Categories do not seem to be ordinal, and you can estimate variance threshold easier when dealing with 0/1 content with bernoulli's `p * (1-p)`: 90% of the same value matches 0.09 variance.

Comment: That was great, thanks! An additional clarification that I would like to consider, if you have any piece of advice here, would be to know if there's any rationale on when to delete a feature with many null values. I mean, will my ML models perform better with or without a feature that has less than 10% of real values?

Comment: A feature with lots of missing values is still potentially helpful assuming the data is missing at random. See my answer to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611870).